# Why Hibernate doesn't return anything from the Native Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an application based on Hibernate 4.2 and Spring Boot 1.4. And I have a very specific SQL query which I can not model with HQL in a performant way.

```
log.debug("Request to get all current Bids for station : code {}, bidType {}, versionNum {}", code, bidType, grainProAdminProperties.getPrice().getCurrentVersionNumber());

List<Object[]> result = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
        "select bid.*, tp.price as tp_price, tp.price_nds as tp_priceNds " +
        "from bid, transportation_price tp, station_location lts, partner part, station stat " +
        "where " +
        "   bid.is_active = true and" +
        "   bid.archive_date is null and " +
        "   part.id = bid.elevator_id and " +
        "   part.station_id = stat.id and " +
        "   lts.region_id = stat.region_id and " +
        "   lts.district_id = stat.district_id and " +
        "   (stat.locality_id is null or " +
        "   lts.locality_id = stat.locality_id) and " +
        "   ((cast(tp.station_from_code as text) = lts.code and " +
        "     cast(tp.station_to_code as text) = cast(:code as text)) " +
        " or " +
        "    (cast(tp.station_to_code as text) = lts.code and " +
        "     cast(tp.station_from_code as text) = cast(:code as text))) and " +
        "    cast(bid.bid_type as text) like cast(:bidType as text) and " +
        "    cast(tp.version_number as int) = cast(:versionNumber as int)").
        setResultTransformer(
            new ResultTransformer() {
                @Override
                public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
                    log.warn("Transform tuple: {}, aliases {}", tuple, aliases);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public List transformList(List collection) {
                    return collection;
                }
            }
        ).
        setParameter("code", code).
        setParameter("versionNumber", grainProAdminProperties.getPrice().getCurrentVersionNumber()).
        setParameter("bidType", bidType).
        list();

    log.debug("Result of request: {}", result);
```

In the log file I can see:

```
Request to get all current Bids for station : code 865065, bidType BUY, versionNum 2
Hibernate: select bid.*, tp.price as tp_price, tp.price_nds as tp_priceNds from bid, transportation_price tp, station_location lts, partner part, station stat where    bid.is_active = true and   bid.archive_date is null and    part.id = bid.elevator_id and    part.station_id = stat.id and    lts.region_id = stat.region_id and    lts.district_id = stat.district_id and    (stat.locality_id is null or    lts.locality_id = stat.locality_id) and    ((cast(tp.station_from_code as text) = lts.code and      cast(tp.station_to_code as text) = cast(? as text))  or     (cast(tp.station_to_code as text) = lts.code and      cast(tp.station_from_code as text) = cast(? as text))) and     cast(bid.bid_type as text) like cast(? as text) and     cast(tp.version_number as int) = cast(? as int)
Result of request: []
```

So the returned result is empty. I'm trying to execute absolutely the same request directly in DB with the same parameters and I'm getting 3 results.

Could you please predict why it could be a case?

Comment: Have you tried to hard-code your 3 query parameters as constants in query to check that it's not a binding issue?

Comment: Thank you @GaëlMarziou ! You are right. I'm using Enum BidType as an input parameter and I'v thought that the standard toString() method will be called to be replaced in SQL. But buy some reason it is not true :( Could you please explain for me the reason of this behaivour?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was (as @GaëlMarziou said) in a binding. I'm using Enum BidType as an input parameter for this Query but it was not transformed to string by using standard toString method.

Comment: Great, so you used `name()`method on your enum? It might also depend on how your enum field is mapped to column.

Comment: I've used toString which has default implementation `return name`. The configuration of Enum field is `@NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "bid_type", nullable = false)
    private BidType bidType;`